# Quel est l'antecédent de « lui » dans « Quelques changements que le temps et le caprice lui préparent » ?

Tags: sens, antécédent

<sub>Source: p 32, *The French Language Today: A Linguistic Introduction* (2 ed, 2000) by Battye,  Hintze,  Rowlett</sub>

> [[Source:]](https://books.google.com/books?id=NRNvjjYauOsC&lpg=PA533&ots=_xvDp9ABno&dq=%22le%20caprice%20lui%20preparent%22&pg=PA533#v=onepage&q=%22le%20caprice%20lui%20preparent%22&f=false) C'est dans le siécle de Louis XIV, comme on 
>   l'a dit, que cette éloquence a eu son plus grand éclat, et que la langue 
>   a été fixée. Quelques changements que le temps et le caprice **lui** préparent, les bons auteurs du XVIIe et du XVIIIe siècle serviront toujours 
>   de modèles.

**Lui** est le pronom personnel complément 3e singulier, mais dans la phrase dans laquelle il est employé ci-dessus, tous les sujets sont pluriels masculins : d'où mon échec de repérer l’antécédent.

Comment: Les trois antécédents possibles présents dans cet extrait sont tous au singulier: "le siècle", "l'éloquence" et "la langue". Le premier n'aurait aucun sens, un siècle passé ne change pas avec le temps, le deuxième n'en a guère plus, l'éloquence des paroles est liée aux locuteurs et ces derniers ne traversent pas les siècles. Ce ne peut donc être que la langue qui, elle, évolue bien au fil du temps et de manière plus ou moins imprévisible (caprice).

Answer (score 3):

*Lui* = *la langue française* qui est le sujet principal et récurrent dans les phrases précédentes du texte, et le coeur du développement.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to the @Bergueradj answer I want to bring a precision to the last part of the answer, responding to:

> mais dans la phrase dans laquelle il est employé ci-dessus, tous les sujets sont pluriels masculins

In "the C.O.I. (lui in this case) can be single or plural", we see that single and plural imples using different pronouns. Imagine we change the source text, like this:

> C'est dans le siécle de Louis XIV, comme on l'a dit, que cette éloquence **et cette verve ont** eu **leur** plus grand éclat, et que la langue a été fixée.

In this version, now "lui" must be replaced by "leur":

> Quelques changements que le temps et le caprice **leur** préparent, ...

because it refers to both "éloquence" and "verve":

> Quelques changements que le temps et le caprice préparent **à l'éloquence et à la verve**, ...

Now at the opposite, "lui" (and "leur" in the modified example above) can be masculine or feminine, *without changing the pronoun used*.
This is the point that motivates the astonishment of the OP, because of some ambiguity. The word "lui" may belong to, either:

- the "tonique" personal pronouns `lui, elle, eux, elles`, which directly indicates the person or the thing it refers to.
  Probably the OP related to this kind of word.
- the "atone" personal pronouns `lui, leur`, which means `à lui | à elle, à eux | à elles`.
  It's the involved kind of word here.

Comment: @Begueradj Oh, now I understand and I'm sorry. My erroneous interpretation of your sentence has been guided by the fact I was focused on to explain the ambiguity (the same word for masculne/feminine) that was the cause of the OP's astonishment: so I (too quickly) concluded you're targeting this ambiguity. Anyway, thanks for your fair attitude.

Comment: @Begueradj After posting my previous comment I lately realized I should modify my answer accordingly! Now that's done Sorry again.

Comment: Even without adding «et cette verve», would the following versions of the original, reinterpreted to require «leur», make sense? 1-(…ET que la langue a été fixée. Quelques changements que le temps et le caprice **leur** [l'éloquence ET la langue] préparent, …);  2-(…Quelques changements que le temps et le caprice **leur** [l'éloquence ET son plus grand éclat] préparent, …); 3-cf (C'est dans ce siècle que Anne a eu son premier fils, et que la monarchie a été rétablie. Quelques changements que le temps et le caprice **leur** [Anne ET son 1er fils {ET peut-être même la monarchie}] préparent, …)?

Comment: @PapaPoule I'm incertain to distinguish on which exact point you ask for confirmation. What is sure is that yes, all your three examples need "lui" to be replaced by "leur". But these examples just illustrate the inescapable ambiguity when there are more than two "good" candidate as related C.O.I.: 1) "leur" becomes mandatory if the author retains at least two of them, and then the reader has no other way than interpreting the context to decide which ones are really involved; 2) more widely, with one (>>"lui") or more (>>"leur") candidates, their gender will never be of any help.

Comment: Merci ! C’est un «moot point (mort?)» maintenant car le malentendu a été bien résolu, mais ma question et mes exemples étaient conçues (avant cette résolution) plutôt pour explorer **la possibilité** que la dernière phrase de la réponse de @Begueradj  (**même** mal interprétée comme vous l’aviez fait au début) pourrait être considérée comme complètement correcte **si** (même sans changer le texte original [en ajoutant «et cette verve», par exemple]) il existait déjà au moins une interprétation du texte original qui exigeait «leur» en place de «lui» en regroupant les antécédents possibles.

Comment: @PapaPoule Oh yes, that's clear, thanks. But now there is something else I don't understand :) In "C’est un «moot point (mort?)» maintenant": 1) is "moot" a typo, or it participates to some joke I didn't discern? 2) Anyway, I can't figure out what means "moot point" (or "mot point"). However, fortunately, I well hear the wordplay with "point (mort ?)".

Comment: Ahh "moot point"! Justement j'avais aussi du mal pour trouver comment le dire en Francais donc normal que vous en aviez pour me comprendre! La traduction "officielle" est "un point discutable" d'apres mes dicos, mais ca ne me plaisait pas du tout car pour moi "a moot point" est plutot une question/(un point de discussion) qui "**n'est plus** discutable" car elle a deja ete resolue, donc j'hesitais m'en servir (erreur de ma part, je crois). Un synonym pour "moot point" est "**It's** [an] **academic** [point]," qui s'agit aussi d'une observation (comme la mienne) qui ne sert plus grand chose.

Comment: @PapaPoule Wow, what a [quiproquo](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56017/english-equivalent-of-french-quiproquo-bis)! I didn't had the idea to regard "moot" as an English word. Now for what you wanted to express, I think we could say "C'est maintenant un point de réthorique" or "Ce n'est plus qu'un point de réthorique" (don't confuse whith "théorique"). But it seems rather high-level language, and for now I can't think to something more relaxed.

Comment: Mise à jour! Ma femme française (qui évidemment connait pas seulement le français mieux que moi, mais l’anglais aussi!)  vient de m’informer que le sens principal ET original de «a moot point» en anglais (britannique) est effectivement «un point discutable» et que donc la traduction dans mes dicos est tout a fait correcte! Le sens que j’ai donné en haut n’est qu’un nouveau sens compris plutôt ici, aux États-Unis. Mea culpa encore une fois!(et merci bcp pour "un point de réthorique" qui capte parfaitement le sens "americain" que je cherchais [et que ma femme ne trouvait pas nonplus]!)

Comment: @PapaPoule Last (but not least??? :) point: I guess that you're responsible of the upvote I just noticed on my question about "quiproquo". Thanks for that. But there is a funny kind of "mise en abyme" (ask your wife for that if needed): if you'd the curiosity to follow the 2nd link I cited in that question's introductory, you'd notice that the answer I posted there was inspired from another one, which was yours! A bit twisted, maybe, but hopefully actually clear...

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Following your link, and once noted that it was an "official" Canadian page, I suddenly realized something that seems to me of interest: in these forums (French language, but also English language Learners), a Canadian source is sort of "bridge". Not only (as we always know) when the source is a person (english-, french-, or both-speaker), but especially when it is a country-level organization: as it is forced to practice the two languages, it _must_ have already think to a lot of issues about equivalence of terms/expressions between them, and might be a good referential.

Comment: Alors les votes peuvent rester anonymes, non? (he said jokingly) Mais ceci dit, votre question et sa seule réponse étaient bonnes et donc méritaient tous les upvotes qu’elles ont eu. Pour le «mise en abyme» (il m’a fallu chercher mes dicos car ma femme pense que j’ai déjà fermée l’ordi!) , je me souviens bien de cette autre question et de mon commentaire a votre réponse mais je ne faisais pas de rapport avant cliquer, juste maintenant, sur le lien!

Comment: @PapaPoule Many thanks for the kind words. And sorry to have broken the privacy policy :). On the other hand, and totally seriously, there's something to explain why I could be easily awareness of the link (in France we'd say "percuter"): unlike me, you chose a pseudo that never goes unnoticed, at least to French eyes!

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Je ne récuse pas le bémol apporté par vos observations, et je ne prétends pas qu'on devrait considérer ce genre de source comme _la_ référence. En revanche je constate que son existence, à l'exemple de la page où menait votre lien, constitue un plus : on y trouve _déjà consignés_ les résultats d'une démarche de réflexion analogue à celle que nous faisons tous ici quotidiennement et collectivement. Et le plus, c'est que cette démarche a forcément dû se frotter à la difficulté de trouver des équivalences comprises/acceptées par les différentes communautés linguistiques.